# Subcategory in Autodesk Platform Services PropertyPanel

Tags: autodesk-forge

based on the tutorial on the APS website I created an extension with a panel. The panel is a PropertyPanel (like summary extension) and will be generated automaticly through some loops. My Question is: With the command .addProperty(name, value, category) I will create a new line in the panel. Is there a similar command availible the get a list, like

- 1. 
- - 1.1.
- - - Name - Value
- - - Name1 - Value
- - 1.2.
- - - Name - Value
- - - Name1 - Value
- 2. 

? 
With the regular command there will be only

- 1. 
- - Name - Value
- - Name1 - Value
- 2. 
- - Name - Value
- - Name1 - Value

two levels possible.

Thanks

I was just trying to put the subcategory in the third parameter or put another command in the third parameter, but nothing happend that I search/expect. Also some searches in the web are unsuccesfull.

Comment: The addProperty() method is used to add different kinds of data to the PropertyPanel. Are you trying to add some custom properties or data to the PropertyPanel?

Comment: @TimmyTim Yes, I add some custom data to the propertyPanel and also order they in categories. I search a method/functionality to write categories inside a category (subcategory), so that the onCategoryClick Method works with all inside. There musst be a method, because I see in the predefined properties panel it works while selecting two or more different elements. But I don't know where I find these code to take a look.